# How to make the application reads a comma as a decimal in VB

Tags: visual-studio, basic

Each computer reads the decimal in a different way. There are computers that use dots and others use commas to read decimals. I have a database that uses commas as decimals. Is there a code that I can use so that every computer that uses my application reads the comma as decimal without having to make changes to the settings on each computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.Globalization
....
Private DecimalSepPt As Boolean ' . is decimal separator and not ,
....
DecimalSepPt = (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".")
```

this will tell you if the country of the PC uses a . or a ,
I used it like this:

```
                    If Not DecimalSepPt Then ' if they use the ,:
                        Stack.Add(CStr(num).Replace(","c, "."c))
                    Else
                        Stack.Add(CStr(num))
                    End If
```

to be sure that CDlbl(..) results in the expected number

Comment: pleasure, even though a little late